# ¿Se puede guardar varias ventanas modales en un archivo aparte?

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Disculpen la molestia.Hasta hace poco estaba implementando varias ventanas modales Bootstrap en mi sitio web.El problema es(no se si lo es)que cada código html lo inserto en la misma pagina donde estos son llamados mediante botones.Tengo alrededor de 4 ventanas modales para diferentes cosas.

Entonces se me ocurrió la idea de si se podría implementar en un archivo aparte todas las ventanas modales y hacerle un include("")con php en las paginas que yo quiero que estén disponible(las modales).

Es buena idea así?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi poca experiencia, yo considero que lo que pretendes si se puede, además de que te ayuda a tener tu código más organizado en caso de que otra persona lo revise a futuro,  pero esa decisión ya depende de ti y si es buena idea implementarlo de esa forma como deseas.

Comment: Por eso es que lo pregunto.Solo estaba buscando algunas respuestas para salir de dudas.Lo probare!!! Y volveré a marcar como respuesta.